# Varying Voltage across a DC motor

Tags: motor, dc, solar-cell

I have a solar panel hooked up to a 12 V battery that it powering a DC motor. What is an easy, efficient way for me to change the voltage across the motor. I would like to include a knob so I can change the voltage, and I would also like to include LEDs like a bar graph to show the relative speed.

Thank you stack exchange community.

Comment: It is not really that simple. Could you maybe explain a little more about what you are trying to accomplish? Do you want to manually speed up and slow down the motor by adjusting the voltage, or what is your motivation for changing the voltage? If you have links to the motor and or the solar panel, that would also be helpful.

Comment: I agree with @mkeith, this is not a simple question. You're assuming that the voltage coming out of your panel is going to be constant as you vary the load and it most certainly is not. If you were just interested in maintaining voltage across the motor, you would use something like a SEPIC converter. However, with motors we're usually interested in the current. Your panel will only provide so much current before it begins to sag like crazy. Just a few more things to think about.

Answer (score 1):

If the DC motors don't draw too much current you can conciser an LM317, it's not difficult to use, and for the graph you can use an LM3914, both are simple to connect and use.

[image: a]
<sub>(source: [eleccircuit.com](http://www.eleccircuit.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/12/voltage-regulator.png))</sub>

[image: b]

Comment: Worth quantifying "not too much current" esp. with respect to starting the motor, and saying something about heatsinking the LM317.